Combining Multi project in visual studio
i have a Torch Project in my visual studio i want to create GUI for that project i need to use QT now the project by default is settled up for Libtorch now i want to compile the QT as well in the same project how is this possible ???
1: I tried adding both to single project and the QT files are not part of the build
2: I can't and don't want to create TorchProject.dll or linking methods between projects

You will be combine two very heavy projects with a lot of dependencies.
I could see you running into problem with transitive dependencies.
Check out this GUI for Torch.
https://www.torchstudio.ai/
Or maybe a normal web interface using Flask or FastAPI would be easier.
